# QtCreator and Clang

Tags: c++, qt-creator, clang

I am trying to use QtCreator and Clang but mostly I don't get any error messages.

if I write

```
// To provoke an error message
int test(){
    return "hi";
}
```

Qt prints me the following

```
D:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.1\bin\CTest\main.cpp:-1: In function 'int test()':
:-1: error: [debug/main.o] Error 1 File not found
```

I compiled clang by myself and it I get working binaries, just no error messages. I selected the Clang compiler in QtCreator with clang.exe.

Comment: `int test() { return "hi"; }` seems nasty, by the way.

Comment: It is on purpose to see the error message. sublime with clang gives the the correct error message

Comment: Ah OK, that was not clear to me, sorry.